# How to click the date picker selenium VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'd like to use selenium VBA to download some data from [Yahoo Finance KOSPI COmposite Index](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EKS11/history?period1=1484018309&period2=1515554309&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d/).

I got the difficulty when click the date picker arrow to get the mini window to select the end date as today. I tried to record the marco through selenium IDE in chrome, but IDE does not record the step when I click the arrow of the Time period to get the date picker visible.

Below is my code in VBA.

```
Public Function seleniumKorea(bot As WebDriver)
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EKS11/history?period1=1484018309&period2=1515554309&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
    bot.Start "chrome", url
    bot.Get "/"

    'Not sure how to add date picker here        
    bot.FindElementByName("endDate").Clear
    bot.FindElementByName("endDate").SendKeys (Date)
    bot.FindElementByXPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='End Date'])[1]/following::button[1]").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))

    bot.FindElementByXPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='As of'])[1]/following::div[4]").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
    bot.FindElementByXPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Currency in KRW'])[1]/following::span[2]").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
End Function
```

I tried to use the ByXPath to get the svg class but failed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. It should serve the purpose. I used `xpath` to solve the issue.

```
Sub CustomizeDate()
    Const Url$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EKS11/history?period1=1484018309&period2=1515554309&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

    With driver
        .get Url
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@data-test='date-picker-full-range']", timeout:=5000).Click
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='startDate']").Clear.SendKeys ("01/05/2017")
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='endDate']").Clear.SendKeys ("01/08/2017")
        .FindElementByXPath("//button/span[.='Done']", timeout:=5000).Click
        .FindElementByXPath("//button/span[.='Apply']", timeout:=5000).Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Don't use hardcoded delay for any item to appear. Use `Explicit Wait` instead. The script will wait upto `5000`, meaning 5 seconds for that item to be available.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following which submits the OATH consent if required and scrolls the date picker into the viewport

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DatePicking()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EKS11/history?period1=1484018309&period2=1515554309&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d/"

    With d
        .get URL
        If .Title = "Yahoo is now part of Oath" Then
            .FindElementByCss("form").submit
        End If

        With .FindElementByCss("[data-test='date-picker-full-range']")
            .ScrollIntoView
            .Click
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("[name=startDate]")
            .Clear
            .SendKeys "05/10/2017"
        End With

        With .FindElementByCss("[name=endDate]")
            .Clear
            .SendKeys "05/10/2017"
        End With
        Stop                                     '<==Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Your method worked well, but I need to click the Done button after input the correct date. I tried the method you mentioned above.`With .FindElementByCss("[name=Done]")
            .Click
        End With` but failed. Shall I ask how to click the done button on this data picker.

Comment: I didn't get this message I'm afraid so my answer was to exactly what you asked. Sorry. But SIM has provided you with that part.